# How can I add a scale reference to the Z axis

Tags: 3d-view, workflow

Blender has a convenient reference grid with 1-unit squares, centered on (0,0,0) in the X-Y plane; **I want something similar on the Z axis**.

I know I can add reference images to the background, and I could create one manually for this purpose ... but having to go to a separate program and import a specially created image seems excessive when I just want a simple ruler to eyeball things against. My current workaround is to add several plane meshes to make a vertical line of squares that I can measure against - but again, it feels like there should be an easier way to do it.

**Is there a quick and easy way to do this?** Ideally, it would let me set a custom interval for the gridlines/ruler ticks, but I'd accept the standard 1-unit ticks if that's the best I can get.

Comment: have you tried the orthographic views? - they will show a grid in all three orientations. -- font, left, top ... back, right, bottom .

Comment: @zeffi I _knew_ I'd end up kicking myself over this one. No, I hadn't thought of trying orthographic view, but that gave me what I was looking for. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll give it the tick; either way, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Easiest option

Orthographic views tend to be useful for this. Even if you're eyeballing there will be less distortion in the perception of location. Orthographic views will show a grid in all three orientations. -- font, left, top ... and their reverse: back, right, bottom. See the Blender manual for all options, and [menus relating to this](https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/navigating/3d_view.html?highlight=views)

[image]

Here Front, Top and Left are visible.

#### possibly interesting option

An addon called 'Chromoly Ruler' or just 'Ruler', is included in the `addons_contrib`. If you get blender from somewhere like [builder.blender.org](https://builder.blender.org/download/). It looks like this

[image]

Comment: It seems that this ruler is no more present in blender 2.79 ver. It is present until 2.78